# iMessage buddy list

Tags: macos, messages

I want to use iMessage on Mountain Lion for my Google Talk buddies. However, the main chat window just shows recent contacts down the left bar, and not my online buddies. I can bring up a seperate window to show my online buddies by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> but this is lame, I want it all in one screen.

Is there any setting anywhere I'm missing or do I have to return to Adium?

Answer (score 2):

Hit command 1 or go to window and click on on buddies. Should bring up the buddy list.

Comment: He mentioned in his question that he knew about Cmd + 1, but didn't like it opening in a new window. Are you aware of another way to bring up the buddy list, like he described?

Answer (score 0):

Messages > Preferences > General > Show status in menu bar.

You can see all your online buddies with this. You can even change your status or go offline.

Comment: this only shows the online buddies from the recent list..

Comment: Nope, it shows all online buddies.

Comment: Oh yes, it does. It doesn't show people who are away. Still, I don't like this UI at all. A chat client shouldn't hide away all the contacts. No one of your finer products Apple..

Comment: SO click the arrows next to the categories.  :)